# reading all the text files from directory

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python and I am using following code to pull output as sentiment analysis:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3Beta
import urllib.request
import codecs
import csv
import os
import re
import sys
import collections
import glob
ipath = 'C:/TEMP/' # input folder
opath = 'C:/TEMP/matrix/' # output folder
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3Beta(
    url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api',
    username='ABCID',
    password='ABCPASS',
    version='2016-02-11')
path = 'C:/TEMP/*.txt'   
file = glob.glob(path)
text = file.read()
data=tone_analyzer.tone(text='text')
for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
    print('Category:', cat['category_name'])
    for tone in cat['tones']:
        print('-', tone['tone_name'],tone['score'])
        #create file
```

In the above code all I am trying to do is to read the file and do sentiment analysis all the text file stored in C:/TEMP folder but I keep getting and error :'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Not sure where I am going wrong and I would really appreciate any help with this one. Also, is there a way i can write the output to a CSV file so if I am reading the file

ABC.txt and I create a output CSV file called ABC.csv with output values.

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*glob* returns a list of files, you need to iterate over the list, open each file and then call *.read* on the *file object*:

```
files = glob.glob(path)
# iterate over the list getting each file 
for fle in files:
   # open the file and then call .read() to get the text 
   with open(fle) as f:
      text = f.read()
```

Not sure what it is exactly you want to write but the [csv lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) will do it:

```
from csv import writer

files = glob.glob(path)
# iterate over the list getting each file
for fle in files:
   # open the file and then call .read() to get the text
   with open(fle) as f, open("{}.csv".format(fle.rsplit(".", 1)[1]),"w") as out:
       text = f.read()
       wr = writer(out) 
       data = tone_analyzer.tone(text='text')
       wr.writerow(["some", "column" ,"names"]) # write the col names
```

Then call `writerow` passing a list of whatever you want to write for each row.

Comment: Thank you Padraic, that did the trick.  Do you know if there is a way I can write the output in seperate CSV files. So if the text file names are abc.txt and xyz.txt is it possible to create the two files abc.csv and xyz.csv containing outputs.

Comment: @Rvs, yep, what are you writing to the csv?

Comment: Thanks Padraic, so if the output after doing the logic on A.txt is X,Y,Z.  I am looking create a CSV file A.CSV containing this output and if output for a file B.txt should be saved in B.CSV. I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: We create a .csv using the name of the fle minus the extension, abc.txt would mean we create a file abc.csv, this is what you want? As far as the data goes, you just write each row as you iterate, I don't know exactly what you want to write to the csv but it will be `wr.writerow([some, row, data])`

Comment: Thanks Padaric, that is exactly what I am looking to do. I would post it as a separate question just to make it more clear.

Comment: glob.glob(pathname)
Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which must be a string containing a path specification. pathname can be either absolute (like /usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile) or relative (like ../../Tools/*/*.gif), and can contain shell-style wildcards. Broken symlinks are included in the results (as in the shell). ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html