# Creating CSV file with output of python code

Tags: python, csv

I am looking to write a python code that will take the text from multiple .txt files in a directory and run the text against 'Tone analyzer' to do the analysis of the tone. So if I have two files ABC.txt and XYZ.txt. I am looking to do the tone analysis on both the file and create two output files ABC.csv and XYZ.csv containing output of the tone analysis here is what I have so far:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3Beta
import urllib.request
import codecs
import csv
import os
import re
import sys
import collections
import glob
ipath = 'C:/TEMP/' # input folder
opath = 'C:/TEMP/matrix/' # output folder
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3Beta(
    url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api',
    username='1f2fd51b-d0fb-45d8-aba2-08e22777b77d',
    password='XYXPASS',
    version='2016-02-11')
path = 'C:/TEMP/*.txt'   
files = glob.glob(path)
# iterate over the list getting each file 
for fle in files:
   # open the file and then call .read() to get the text 
   with open(fle) as f:
      text = f.read()
output = f.replace('txt', 'csv')
output = open(opath + output, mode = 'w')
data=tone_analyzer.tone(text='text')
for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
    for tone in cat['tones']:
        print(tone['tone_name'],tone['score'])
        #create file
```

I am able to print the tone analysis output but not sure how to save them separately in two csv files.  I would really appreciate any insights here.

Thank You

Comment: Every time you read a file, you write a file, so what if you put the part about writing files (the last few lines) inside the loop over all the files?  Also, rather than printing to the screen, don't you want to actually use the output variable and write to the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading all the text files from directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534141/reading-all-the-text-files-from-directory)

Comment: Thanks John, how would I do that? and how do I append it in separate files?

Answer (score 0):

Simply save loop output to lists and then use `csv` module's `writerow()` to write lists to file. Below will save `tone['tone_name']` and `tone['tone_score']` data to csv files with `output` serving as the unique identifier in file name (extension .txt removed).

```
...
# iterate over the list getting each file 
for fle in files:
    # open the file and then call .read() to get the text 
    with open(fle) as f:
        text = f.read()

    # tone analysis
    data=tone_analyzer.tone(text='text')

    # iterate through tone analysis data
    tonename=[]; tonescore=[]
    for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
        for tone in cat['tones']:
             tonename.append(tone['tone_name'])
             tonescore.append(tone['score'])
             print(tone['tone_name'],tone['score'])

    # output tone name and score to file
    output = fle.replace('.txt', '')     
    with open(opath + output + '_tonename.csv', mode = 'w') as csvfile1:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile1) 
        for i in tonename:
             writer.writerow([i])

    with open(opath + output + '_tonescore.csv', mode = 'w') as csvfile2:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile2) 
        for i in tonescore:
             writer.writerow([i])
```

Should you need one csv file containing both columns, no lists are even needed:

```
for fle in files:
    # open the file and then call .read() to get the text 
    with open(fle) as f:
        text = f.read()

    # tone analysis
    data=tone_analyzer.tone(text='text')

    # output tone name and score to file
    output = fle.replace('.txt', '')   
    with open(opath + output + '.csv', mode = 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile) 
        writer.writerow(['tone_name','score'])                         # HEADERS
        for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
             for tone in cat['tones']:
                 print(tone['tone_name'],tone['score'])

                 writer.writerow([tone['tone_name'],tone['score']])    # ROWS
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I am getting following error while I try to add this code: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 730: character maps to <undefined>.   I appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry one update, tried to run the the code again but this time I am getting an error:  AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'. I would really appreciate any help with this one.

Comment: Replace the `f` with `fle` in: `output = fle.replace('.txt', '')`.

Comment: Thank you Parfait, one last question, is there any way I can get both tone_name and scores in the same file as two columns.

Comment: That was my original answer until I re-read your question and needed two files! See edit as you do not even need the lists.