# python-Create a csv by reading and processing files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

So I am trying to read a set of files and run them through a function that returns a set of numbers. I need to write a csv with header and I need the name of the file as the first column of the csv.

I have tried using the following code to write the csv

```
path = 'input/files'
opath = 'output/csvs'
col_names = [file, n1,n2,n3,n4,n5]

tmp = np.sort(glob.glob(path))

csvfile = open('opath/test.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile),delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
writer.writerow(col_names)  #writing header for the csv

for t in tmp:
    img = np.load(t)   
    writer.writerow([t, test(t))

csvfile.close()
```

Where `test()` is a dummy function that I am using to reproduce the output from my function. It basically reads a file and creates numbers after doing processing. So it takes the already loaded file `t` and prints out the  result of calculation.

```
def test(f):
    for i in range(f):
        print i,i+1,i-1,2*i
```

For the last `test()`function I have tried using:

```
print [i,i+1,i-1,2*i]
return [i,i+1,i-1,2*i]
```

so I can have a list to parse into the `writerow()`, but that does not seem to work either.

The output that I have received looks like this

```
file1,"[(1,4,3,5)]"
file1,"(1,4,3,5)"
```

instead of the wanted output: `file1,1,4,3,5`

I don't want to use string methods to edit each row as I will be reading a lot of files thus making my csvs quite large and I know it is not the right way to do it.

Also, I don't think storing each output separately as lists will work as it will take much more time to do the file processing. I tried following the ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534942/creating-csv-file-with-output-of-python-code) but the output of the processing function seems easier to handle and the problem seems a little different.

Any advice or insight as to how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your posting includes undefined variables and at least one syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the question can be summarized actually. How can I change the output of the test function so that when writing the csv it doesn't prints a string but the actual sequence if numbers produced? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, you have to send `writerow` a list of the things you want printed.  Your current code gives it two elements: an integer and a list.  That's what you get in the output line.

I think you want something like the code below.  `test` returns a list.  Instead of adding that as a single element with four elements of its own, you want to send `writerow` a list of five elements.  Make a list of `t` and those four elements.  I've coded it very simply below; you can collapse it once you understand how it works.

```
for t in range(5,8):
    line = [t]
    line.extend(test(t))
    # print line
    writer.writerow(line)
```

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Great! It worked. I will take in the feedback to improve future questions.